# Sum contracted hours once across multiple rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have a table that has employees booked annual leave. In this table are the employees contracted hours based on roles.

[image]

In the column on the right, it is totaling all the hours for Jane Doe for each role.

```
=SUMIFS([Contract hours],[Full Name],[@[Full Name]],[Role],[@Role])
```

What I would like is that it only sums the role once and add the two values together so the value in 'Total Contracted Hrs' is 40

Comment: This is probably a question for SuperUser, not StackOverflow.

Comment: What is your excel version? With Excel365 you can use Filter, Unique and SUM function.

Comment: I have Excel365

Comment: As it's written, your question is unclear how you want the expected results. I see the contract hours for each role repeat, but will these vary in the actual dataset? This sounds like you want duplicates, but by using a sum? It sounds like you're looking for a summary table, not to sum everything by role in the table itself?

Comment: @AlanB - as matter of interest, can you provide link describing what should be classified as Stack vs Super pls? Ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j99C7NRwjgQoN9KN9V?e=VErYrr)/screenshots refer:

**Version 1 -**

*Pre-req: Office 365 compatible version Excel*

[image: Version 1 - Office 365]

```
=SUM(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$C$5,--($A$2:$A$5=A2))))
```

*note: *EDIT* - *in general* its impossible to create array / spill using `sum` - thus have to 'bullet' fixed references, and drag down (not sure you can create spill eqn. in table anyways; notwithstanding, above still applicable --)*

**Version 2 -**

*Any version*

*In table*

[image: Version 2 - in table]

```
=SUM(INDEX($I$2:$L$5,0,MATCH(A2,$I$1:$L$1,0)))
```

*Interim lookup*

[image: Version 2 - interim lookup]

```
=AVERAGEIFS($C$2:$C$5,$B$2:$B$5,H2,$A$2:$A$5,I$1)
```

*Note: can drag this equation down/across table as req.*